# HttpUrlConnection in Android no error but not working

Tags: android, http, httpclient, httpurlconnection

I am not familiar with the HttpUrlConnection on Android Studio. I tried to code using HttpClient in Eclipse and it works. HttpClient is now deprecated in Android Studio so I tried changing it with the HttpUrlConnection. My code in Android Studio is like this:

```
public String LedOff(View view) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://192.168.4.1/LEDOff");
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.connect();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

in Eclipse it is like this:

```
public void LedOff (View view){

        String url = "http://192.168.4.1/LEDOff";

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        try {
            httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

I dont know what's wrong. please help me guyssss. thanks.

Comment: please paste your logcat..

Comment: Are you behind a proxy ?

Comment: 05-19 15:27:12.727 21143-21150/com.ganda.alex.http D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400067C7, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
05-19 15:27:12.727 21143-21150/com.ganda.alex.http D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
05-19 15:27:13.228 21143-21150/com.ganda.alex.http D/jdwp: processIncoming


my logcat is just like that all over

Comment: Yes I am behind a proxy. I'm using a webserver to control the arduino.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have these two permissions in your Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

**Edit**
Added code to `LedOff()` method to treat a successful response as a `String`.

And try this, as per [Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html#download):

```
public String LedOff(View view) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://192.168.4.1/LEDOff");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET"); // Or any method you need
        conn.setDoInput(true);

        // Starts the query
        conn.connect();
        int response = conn.getResponseCode();
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "The response code is: " + response);

        if ((response >= 200) && (response < 300)) {
            // We are assuming here that whatever the response is, it can be parsed as a String
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "The response is: " + conn.getResponseMessage());
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        // Handle any exceptions
    }
}
```

Comment: can please give me an example of response. I'm so sorry because I'm just a newbie here. this is my first time setting http connections.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to achieve by connecting to "**http://192.168.4.1/LEDOff**" ?

Comment: I have edited my answer and included code to treat a successful response as a `String`.

Comment: well the 192.168.4.1/LedOff actually turns off a LED. The LED is already programmed in arduino so I decided to just get the url then just put it in arduino for easier programming.

Comment: Android -> WebServer -> Arduino something like this

Comment: I assume that you are not expecting any specific response from server, only if it succeeded or not. Just checking the response code to be in the range [200,300) or `(responseCode >= 200) && (responseCode < 300)` should be enough for your needs. Does the code I have provided you works ? Does the led turns off ?

Comment: sadly it doesn't work. but thank you for answering my questions. I'll just try to modify your given program

Comment: What the response code and response message of the server ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to commit the request by calling `getInputStream()`, `getResponseCode()`, or `getResponseMessage()` for the response to be returned and processed.

`Connect()` method just creates the connection.

**Check with :**

```
Log.i("Response Code" , urlConnection .getResponseCode());
```

See what response are you getting.

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
    URL url = new URL("http://192.168.4.1/LEDOff");
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true)
    urlConnection.connect();
    if(urlConnection.getResponseCode()==200)
    {
     ...
    }
```